# Can a Custom URL Protocol call a javascript function

Tags: javascript, url, vbscript, protocols

In a windows custom url protocol as defined similar to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

The handler function is vbscript.

Is it possible for the vbscript to call a javascript function in the html page which call it?

Or is there a way for the html page to know when the custom url protocol has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"Shell.Application"` object to locate iexplorer window, and access its window and document properties. You can insert (`window.document.createElement('script')`) code inside the page to do what you need

Comment: No AFAIK. Windows keeps track of existing instances off browser windows and gives you access to them, exposing their object model through COM. Firefox or Chrome are not part of the operating system, they have not the same integration. You will need to reimplement a similar/better mechanism via NPAPI, ActiveX, extension, plugin, ... whatever that allow to expose the DOM to the operating system.